# How to use start command to open a file on the folder it is contained (without typing the folder name)

Tags: batch-file, filepath

I'm using .bat files to open multiple pdf books at the same time, here's an example:

```
@echo off

start "Constazo" "D:\Docs\Leitura\Medicine and biology\Physiology\(Costanzo Physiology) Linda S. Costanzo PhD-Physiology_ with STUDENT CONSULT Online Access, 5e-Saunders (2013).pdf"
start "guyton" "D:\Docs\Leitura\Medicine and biology\Physiology\Guyton12e.pdf"
start "constazo br" "D:\Docs\Leitura\Medicine and biology\Physiology\Constazo4eptbr.pdf"
start "Physio integrated" "D:\Docs\Leitura\Medicine and biology\Physiology\Human physiology an integrated approach.pdf"
start "tortora" "D:\Docs\Leitura\Medicine and biology\Anatomy\Tortora.pdf"
```

However, I use these books across many computers, sometimes carrying them on a pen drive. I'd like to know how I can make a version of this script to open the books without having to change the path all the time. The best way I figured I'd do this is by putting the script on the same folder as the books and using a command that says "consider the folder you are in as the path for all files I list". Can anyone help me out with this?

I'm a med student with no experience in programming, and I'm very grateful for your time.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. I've indented your code by 4 spaces so that it renders properly - please see [the editing help](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) for more information on formatting. I've also changed the tags to be more relevant to your question. Good luck.

Comment: `cd %~dp0` changes your working directory to the folder where your batchfile resides. You then can just open your PDFs (in the same folder) without giving any path. (Just `"Guyton12e.pdf"` (without `start` should be enough)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code with batch file being stored in directory `D:\Docs\Leitura\Medicine and biology` or whatever is the directory containing the subdirectories `Physiology` and `Anatomy`:

```
@echo off
cd /D "%~dp0"
start "Constazo" "Physiology\(Costanzo Physiology) Linda S. Costanzo PhD-Physiology_ with STUDENT CONSULT Online Access, 5e-Saunders (2013).pdf"
start "guyton" "Physiology\Guyton12e.pdf"
start "constazo br" "Physiology\Constazo4eptbr.pdf"
start "Physio integrated" "Physiology\Human physiology an integrated approach.pdf"
start "tortora" "Anatomy\Tortora.pdf"
```

For understanding the used commands and how they work, open a command prompt window, execute there the following commands, and read entirely all help pages displayed for each command very carefully.

- `call /?` ... contains explanation for `%~dp0` (drive and path of argument 0 - the batch file).
- `cd /?`
- `echo /?`
- `start /?`